# Centering content with margin:0 auto

Tags: html, css

The following is my CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#header {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 220px;
    font-size: 60pt;

}
#subheader {
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: #666;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

#email {
    width: 165px;
    height: 25px;       
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 2px solid;
    color: #666;
    border-color: black;

}
input[type=submit] {
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

#socialMedia {
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align:center;
}
#video {
    padding-left: 600px;
    margin-top: -260px;

}
</style>
```

The HTML divs are divided as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
    <Content>
</div>
<div id="subheader">
    <Content>
</div>
<Form Input Field>

<div id="video">

<Embedded Video>
</div>

<div id="socialMedia">
    <Social Media Image Links>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having with this is that while the page attempts to center itself with browser rescale, only the left side of the content is really adjusting.  The right side essentially hangs on to the edge of the page, thereby not centering it.

Any suggestions? I tried this using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the problem:

```
#video {
    padding-left: 600px;
    margin-top: -260px;

}
```

I'm not sure what size the video container is but maybe this is why it is not centering properly with everything else.

When you use this CSS instead, what happens?

```
#video {
    text-align:right;
    margin-top: -260px;

}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the problem is. Could you send a screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a max-width on the container:

```
.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltf5U/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmm. That didn't seem to have much effect.  The best I can get it to look is by setting the container with to 1250px.  However, when expanding the browser width significantly,  there is a more whitespace on the right most portion of the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: 'max-width' is the only way (with CSS) that I can think of for preventing right-hand bleed based on your explanation.